# Plotly (Python)- 100+ subplot y axes

Tags: python-2.7, plot, subplot, plotly, multiple-axes

I am working with big data sets where I need to graph multiple stacked trends but have come across an issue relating the the number of y axes allowed in a plotly graph. I have tried multiple methods to resolve this but to no avail.

Anytime I attempt to graph data where I use over 100 y-axes trends the trends begin to eclipse the previous ones. Here is an image of my attempt to graph 106 trends:

[106 trends](https://plot.ly/~Emagnuson/1640/u-37pc0062nd-stage-hp-separator-u-37pc5752nd-stg-east-rx-inlet-u-37lc105d105-ko-/)

If  downsize the number of trends to 99 trends then all of these show in the graph:

[99 trends](https://plot.ly/~Emagnuson/1643/u-37pc0062nd-stage-hp-separator-u-37pc5752nd-stg-east-rx-inlet-u-37lc105d105-ko-/)

I am building these graphs in ipython notebook using plotly's python API.

Does plotly have a limit on the number of y axes that are permitted in one graph?